# NodeJS Sequelize Datamodelling with Custom Reference field

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following model defined:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

// Brand
var Brand = sequelize.define("Brand", {
   name: DataTypes.STRING
},{tableName: "brand"});

// Product_Type
var Product_Type = sequelize.define("Product_Type", {
   name: DataTypes.STRING
},{tableName: "product_type"});

// Product
var Product = sequelize.define("Product", {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  product_type_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: Product_Type,
    referencesKey: "id"
},
brand_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: Brand,
    referencesKey: "id"
},
 weight: DataTypes.INTEGER
},{tableName: "product"});

Brand.hasMany(Product);
Product_Type.hasMany(Product);

Product.belongsTo(Brand);
Product.belongsTo(Product_Type);

return Product;
};
```

I get this error:

```
 Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'BrandId' in 'field list'
```

How can i tell sequelize to use the correct fields? Meaning instead of `BrandId` to use `brand_id` and instead of `ProductTypeId` to use `product_type_id`.
I thought referencing it suffices, or do I to specify it again throught the associations?